# Issues with savefig

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

The code I wrote to produce boxplots was working just fine until I tried to edit one of my figures. Now, the command fig.savefig (or plt.savefig for that matter) does not work at all.

The following code has worked in Spyder for the past month until today. I have tried running it in Jupyter Notebook and python raw as well, but to no avail.

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
d = ['D-4','D-3','D-2','D-1','D']
p = sns.boxplot(data=cdo_mom) #Plots boxplots
plt.setp(p.artists,edgecolor='k') #Changes the colors of the boxes, whiskers, median lines
plt.setp(p.lines,color='k')
p.yaxis.grid(True) #Turns on the y axis grid
p.set_axisbelow(True)
p = sns.swarmplot(data=cdo_mom,color='black') #Displays raw data
p.set(xticklabels=d) #Sets the x label as the name of the volume
plt.text(0,3.4,'n: %s' % len(cdo_mom[0]),color='blue',ha='center',va='bottom') # displays number of observations for each volume
plt.text(1,3.04,'n: %s' % len(cdo_mom[1]),color='orange',ha='center',va='bottom')
plt.text(2,3.04,'n: %s' % len(cdo_mom[2]),color='green',ha='center',va='bottom')
plt.text(3,2.9,'n: %s' % len(cdo_mom[3]),color='red',ha='center',va='bottom')
plt.text(4,3.25,'n: %s' % len(cdo_mom[4]),color='purple',ha='center',va='bottom')
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
ax.get_xticklabels()[0].set_color('red')
ax.get_xticklabels()[1].set_color('red')
ax.get_xticklabels()[2].set_color('red')
ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_color('red')
ax.set_title('D$_0$ Median of Medians For Corrected dataset',fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('D$_0$ (mm)',fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel('Volume',fontsize=16)
fig.savefig(r'D:\Desktop\c_mom\D0_c_mom')
plt.close()
```

I expect these figures to be saved in the directory I provided, but again, this code has unexpectedly stopped working after working for a month

Comment: The edits I made that initially brought this issue to my attention have been changed back, but the result is the same. plt.savefig() does not work even for a basic plot.

Comment: You forgot to tell what "does not work" means. Do you get an error? Does the interpreter crash? First thing to do in such cases is to produce a [mcve].

Comment: it does not save the figure. no error. no crash. all the info I have is given here. If you would like the preceding code before what I have posted to obtain what I have being plotted (cdo_mom in this instance), I can provide you with that...however, it is not a small amount of code

Comment: Also, I realize I should have been a bit clearer....when I say " Now, the command fig.savefig (or plt.savefig for that matter) does not work at all." I mean that I have created a very simple plot..

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('some directory')

and the function does not save. It does not raise an error either or cause a crash or anything.

Comment: The point is more to reduce the actual code to a minimal code which still shows the same problem. Presumably that would be some 5 lines long only. Then for debugging you can try different paths, or savefig arguments etc. to further narrow down the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I appreciate you attempting to help. The function itself ceased working all together, be it in my code posted above or any other attempt at calling the function. It was not anything to do with my code, anaconda updated a few things without my knowledge, and essentially eliminated several key packages. I resolved the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda. In the future, I will be sure to be more specific with the issues I am having so a quick resolution may be possible.